# Parsing Text Files

Tags: python, parsing, text

I am new to python and am looking to parse several text files (~5000) with data that looks like this:

> random text ...
>   **ID: ABC123456**
>
> random text ...
>
> **Title**
>
> Contained Text
>
> **End**
>
> random text ...

Each file has about 3000 lines, and I want to extract the ID and text contained between the lines **Title** and **End** into a csv file, hat looks something like this:

> ID           Text
>
> ABC123456    Contained Text 1
>
> ABC123457    Contained Text 2

Would appreciate any help!

Here is what I have:

```
f = open("test.txt",'r')
while True:
    text = f.readline()
    if 'Title' in text:
        print text
```

Comment: Have you attempted to code anything? Where did those attempts not work?

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for your reply. I am just getting started and used f.readline() to parse the file. However, it takes an unusually long time to read through the entire file. I was wondering if there is a faster way to parse these files?

Comment: Could you post that code, so we're not sailing blind? :)

Comment: Sure, @acdr! As I said, just getting started, so haven't gone very far. But here is what I have: 

`
f = open("test.txt",'r')
while True:
    text = f.readline()
    if 'Title' in text:
 print text
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting something like this in your while loop, after the `readline` line:

```
id = None
title_set = True
f = open("test.txt",'r')
while True:
    text = f.readline()
    if text.startswith("ID: "):
        id = text[4:].strip() # The strip() is to remove the newline
    if text == "End":
        title_set = False
    if text == "Title":
        title_set = True
    if title_set and id is not None:
        print(id + " " + text.strip())
```

This should print all your lines as you want them (barring some formatting).

Writing these lines to another file comes down to replacing `print(...)` by `other_file.write(...)`, where `other_file` is a handle of a different file, opened with writing permission.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @acdr! This works just fine. My actual files are a little more complicated, but I should be able to take it from here. Will reach out if I need more help. Very grateful.